# What is the output of the following code in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
a = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;];

[~ ,im]=sort(reshape(a,1,[])'descend');
```

So what actually is im getting as output,it is not a sorted array?

Comment: Your code has at least one typo; it's probably best to copy&paste what you actually did, not re-type it manually.

Comment: no, you discard the sorted array because of the tilde. What you save to `im`, is the second output argument of sort, being the indices to the input matrix, so that it's values or sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;];
A = reshape(a,1,[]);
[B ,im]=sort(A,'descend');
```

`B` is the sorted horizontal vector.  `im` is the indexes so that `all(A(im)==B)` returns `true`.

You don't particularly need the reshape command, or rather another way to get the same result is

```
A = a(:)';
```

a(:) makes a column vector out of any array, and ' transposes that to a horizontal array.  (' will also complex conjugate the elements of a if they are complex, but yours are not complex so this works here.)

I'm sort of surprised you are not looking for

```
B = sort(a,'descend');
```

which gives a 3x3 matrix output with each column sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html); the second output parameter of `sort` is an array of indices, not an array of values.